# Wcf NetNamedPipesBinding replying slow on heavy load

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, wcf, pipe

I have a wcf server using NetNamedPipesBinding.
I can see when the server is loaded with requests the reply is very slow (1-7 seconds).
The application code runs very fast but the time between sending the reply and receiving the reply takes long.
Is this because there are lots of messages at the pipe and they are processed sequentially ? is there a way to improve that ?

there are only 2 processes involves (caller and service)  and the calls are 2 way, the caller process uses different threads to call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a separate Thread for each request, you could be starving your system.  Since both client and server are on the same machine, it may be the client's fault the server is slow.

There are lots of ways to do multithreading in .NET and a new Thread may be the worst. At worst you should move your calls to the thread pool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx)

or you may want to use the async methods of the proxy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx).